# Query ManyToMany relationship Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

Hey everyone I want to query a `manyToManyField` from my database it seems that it doesn't work. I would like to get from the database model the list of all framework incompatibility. But when I do a query, I get nothing from that.

Here is my models:

```
class Framework(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    typeOfFramework = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfProgram, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pros = models.ManyToManyField(Pro)
    nombreAvantage = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    cons = models.ManyToManyField(Con)
    nombreDesavantage = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    additionalInformation =  models.ForeignKey(web,blank=True,null=True ,default = None ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    incompatibility = models.ManyToManyField("self",blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.name} {0.version} {0.typeOfFramework} {0.nombreAvantage} {0.nombreDesavantage} {0.additionalInformation}'
        return template.format(self)

    def getLanguage(self):
        return ", ".join([p.name for p in self.language.all()])
    def getPros(self):
        return ", ".join([p.advantage for p in self.pros.all()])
    def getCons(self):
        return ", ".join([p.disadvantage for p in self.cons.all()])

    def getIncompatibility(self):
        return ", ".join([(p.name + ' '+ p.version) for p in self.incompatibility.all()])


    def __iter__(self):
        return [ self.name, 
                 self.language,
                 self.version, 
                 self.typeOfFramework,  
                 self.pros, 
                 self.cons, 
                 self.additionalInformation
      ]

class DataPro(models.Model):
    advantage = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.advantage}'
        return template.format(self)

class DataCon(models.Model):
    disadvantage = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.disadvantage}'
        return template.format(self)

class Database(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pros = models.ManyToManyField(DataPro)
    nombreAvantage = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    cons = models.ManyToManyField(DataCon)
    nombreDesavantage = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    frameworkIncompatibility = models.ManyToManyField(Framework, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.name} {0.version} {0.nombreAvantage} {0.nombreDesavantage}'
        return template.format(self)

    def getDataPros(self):
        return ", ".join([p.advantage for p in self.pros.all()])
    def getDataCons(self):
        return ", ".join([p.disadvantage for p in self.cons.all()])
    def getFrameworkIncompatibility(self):
        return ", ".join([p.name + " "+ p.version for p in self.frameworkIncompatibility.all()])
```

And here is the view where I want to get the list of

```
            listOfDatabase = Database.objects.values_list()
            databaseIncompatibility = []
            for s in listOfDatabase:
                databaseIncompatibility.append(s.objects.filter(frameworkIncompatibility__in=Framework.objects.all()))



            listDatabase = [(q[0],q[1],q[2],q[3],q[4])for q in listOfDatabase]
            #ID, name, version, con, pro
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, it's my first `django` project and I'm a bit lost on how to do some things.

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: What error do you get? IMHO `type(s)` returns a tuple, which should result in a AttributeError. If not I assume your code is not executed at all.

Comment: Well I tried with 
`databaseIncompatibility = Database.frameworkIncompatibility.value_list()`
And I got an error.
`AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'value_list'`